# throws keyword in front of main thread

Tags: java, exception

My question is when we use "throws" methodology to throw an exception, why we need to give it in front of main method inspite of already thrown it in respective method which required that like add() method will throw the exception if am using Inputstream reader to take the input, so i used "throws IOException" in front of it and executed the code. But error was coming to handle the IOexception in main thread. So, when i appended "throws IOException" in front of main thread, it executed fine. But i did not get why error was coming in main thread part as add() method was the one to generate the exception and there i handled it.
Please explain this. :)

Code:

```
class A { 

BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

public void add() throws IOException { 
int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
int b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
System.out.println("Value after addition : "+(a+b)); 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
 A a=new A(); a.add(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? :/

Comment: *Please explain this. :)*.... really? **you please explain your question...**

Comment: class A
{ 
BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public void add() throws IOException
{
int a=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
int b=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
SOP("Value after addition : "+(a+b));
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
A a=new A();
a.add();
}
}

Comment: sorry for not mentioning my code earlier

Comment: so your question is about exception propagation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Comment: can you format your code properly and update the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i did not get why error was coming in main thread part as add() method was the one to generate the exception and there i handled it.

No, you didn't handle it there. You let it propagate up to the calling method.

Handling an exception means `catch`ing it and doing something appropriate:

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
    A a=new A(); 
    try {
        a.add(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Don't really know how you want to handle it, so I'll just print a line on System.err.
        System.err.println("add() failed!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Oh... now i got where i was wrong in understanding.. Thank you so much Mr. Lindback. :)

Comment: N thnku guys for bearing my unformatted code. I gave it properly but some problem was coming while uploading it. So apologies. :)

Comment: Add the code to the question. Comments remove the formatting of code that spans more than one line.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "throws" you don't treat your exception. you just say that you don't want to treat it there and you will treat it in other place (the place you call the method).So throwing it from the method means that you have to treat it from the main or any other place you call your method

Comment: yes and if at all i do not handle it in main thread also, then JVM will take care. Right?

Comment: no. you have to surround the block which may cause the exception with a try {}catch(). the JVM can only print the stack trace of the exception if you don't tell him otherwise, as you may see.

Comment: Oh.. got that.. :) thnks to u too :)